# What is the difference between float, _Float32, _Float32x, and _Float32_t?

Tags: c, floating-point, c23, stdfloat

C23 introduced a number of floating point types, including but not limited to:

- `_Float32`
- `_Float32x`
- `_Float32_t`

I am unsure of the differences, such as:

- Are they keywords, or are they type aliases, or something else?
- Are they distinct types, or can they be aliases for `float`?
- What is the minimum range and precision of these types?
- Are they required to be IEEE-754-compliant (or IEC 60559)?
- Is `float` obsoleted by `_Float32` or other types?

The same questions apply to `_Float64` vs `double`, and `_Float128` vs `long double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `_FloatN_t` types (e.g. `_Float32_t`) are aliases from the `<math.h>` header. All the other types are required to be distinct, and their names are keywords. (See [H.5.1 [Keywords]](https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#H.5.1))

All of the types fall into one of four categories (see below). Choose between them as follows:

- `float`, `double`, and `long double`, if you are satisfied with the **very lenient** requirements of these types

  - alternatively, check whether `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` is defined, which makes them stricter
  - also, use `float` and `double` if you are okay with them being the same type<sup>1)</sup>
  - also, you must use these types for compatibility with pre-C23 compilers
- `_FloatN` if you need a specific IEC 60559 type with exactly *N* bits
- `_FloatNx` if you need an extended IEC 60559 type with minimum *N* precision

  - especially if you want to store *N*-bit integers in a floating-point number with no loss
- `_FloatN_t` if you don't need IEC 60559 types, and you are not satisfied with the minimum requirements for `float` and `double`

<sup>1)</sup> *On architectures without a double-precision FPU, `float` and `double` might be the same size (e.g. Arduino). Use other types (e.g. `_Float64_t` over `double`) if you want software emulation of double-precision instead.*

#### Standard floating types

`float`, `double`, and `long double` are collectively called *standard floating types*. Their representation is implementation-defined, but there are some requirements nonetheless:

- `double` must be able to represent any `float`, and `long double` must represent any `double`
- if `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` is defined, `float` and `double` are represented like `_Float32` and `_Float64`
- they must be able to represent some amount of decimal digits with no loss, and have a minimum/maximum value

| Type | Minimum Decimal Digits | Minimum | Maximum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `float` | `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG` ≥ 6 | `FLT_MIN` ≤ 10<sup>-37</sup> | `FLT_MAX` ≥ 10<sup>37</sup> |
| `double` | `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` ≥ 10 | `DBL_MIN` ≤ 10<sup>-37</sup> | `DBL_MAX` ≥ 10<sup>37</sup> |
| `long double` | `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG` ≥ 10 | `LDBL_MIN` ≤ 10<sup>-37</sup> | `LDBL_MAX` ≥ 10<sup>37</sup> |

Usually, `float` and `double` are *[binary32](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)* and *[binary64](//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)* types respectively, and `long double` is *[binary128](//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format)*, an [x87 80-bit extended floating-point number](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format), or represented same as `double`.

*See [C23 Standard - E [Implementation limits]](//www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#E.)*

#### Interchange floating types

`_Float32`, `_Float64` etc. are so called *interchange floating types*. Their representation must follow the IEC 60559 interchange format for binary floating-point numbers, such as *[binary32](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)*, *[binary64](//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)*, etc. Any `_FloatN` types must be exactly *N* bits wide.

The types `_Float32` and `_Float64` might not exist, unless the implementation defines `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` and `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__`. If so:

- `_Float32` exists, and `float` has the same size and alignment as it (but is a distinct type)
- `_Float64` exists, and `double` has the same size and alignment as it (but is a distinct type)
- a wider `_FloatN` (typically `_Float128`) exists if `long double` is a *binaryN* type with *N > 64*

*See [C23 Standard - H.2.1 [Interchange floating types]](//www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#H.2.1).*

#### Extended floating types

`_Float32x`, `_Float64x`, etc. are so called *extended floating types* (named after [IEC 60559 extended precision](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision)). Unlike their interchange counterparts, they only have minimum requirements for their representation, not exact requirements. A `_FloatNx` must have *≥ N* bits of precision, making it able to represent *N*-bit integers with no loss.

These types might not exist, unless the implementation defines `__STDC_IEC_60559_TYPES__`. If so:

- `_Float32x` exists if `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` is defined, and may have the same format as `double` (but is a distinct type)
- `_Float64x` exists if `__STDC_IEC_60559_DFP__` is defined, and may have the same format as `long double` (but is a distinct type)
- in either case, `_Float128x` optionally exists

> The extra precision and range often mitigate round-off error and eliminate overflow and underflow in intermediate computations.

*See [C23 Standard - H.2.3 [Extended floating types]](//www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#H.2.3)*

#### Aliases

`_Float32_t`, `_Float64_t`, etc. are aliases for other *floating types*, so that:

- `_FloatN_t` has at least the range and precision of the corresponding *real floating type* (e.g. `_Float32_t` has the at least the range and precision of `_Float32` if it exists)
- a wider type can represent all values of a narrower one (e.g. `_Float64_t` can represent `_Float32_t`)

*See [C23 Standard - H.11 [Mathematics <math.h>]](//www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#H.11).*